# Can we send DB ResultSet in Java to another server so that rows will be fetched from that separate server?

Tags: java, sql, database

I am running a query and checking if data exists, then I need to stream the 50000+ rows, but that needs to be done by another server. So I want to send the `ResultSet` object somehow to another server where the rows will be fetched. Is it possible?

I could just send SQL query to that another server. But will there be any security issues?

Comment: Such things usually are done with queues (MDB, ActiveMQ and so on). You put your task in a queue, including your ResultSet object or whatever you want, another server pick ups it from the queue and performs the job. In this case there aren't any security issues - you just need to configurate the queue.

Comment: Your app can serve a REST web service that runs the SQL locally and provides the remote server an endpoint where it can connect to and retrieve the data.